# Generics to constrain an N-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

Is there a way to constrain a generic type to be an n-dimensional array?

So, `T[]`, `T[,]`, `T[,,]`, ... etc.

I'm basically trying to add an extension method to any type of arrays of that type I have. So I'm looking to get a combination of these methods using generics so I don't need to repeat the code inside

```
public static bool IsFull(this MyType[] self) { ... }
public static bool IsFull(this MyType[,] self) { ... }
public static bool IsFull(this MyType[,,] self) { ... }
```

One method looks like this, but should have the exact same logic for `[,]`, `[,,]` etc:

```
public static bool IsFull(this MyType[] self)
    for (int i=0; i < self.Length; i++) {
        MyType t = self.GetValue(i);
        if (t == null || !t.IsFull()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: With T4, you should be able to do something like this. Otherwise, I don't know any type of constraint to do what you are looking for in C#.

Comment: how will the exact same logic work for more than 1 dimension, you're reading `self[i]` into a `MyType` variable?

Comment: @KMoussa Ah yea I'd have to change that to `GetValue`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll eventually have to check if your array element is an instance of `MyType` or another array - if that's acceptable then perhaps you can add an extension on `System.Array` - something like this:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool IsFull(this Array self)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < self.Length; i++)
        {
            var t = self.GetValue(i);
            var arrT = t as Array;
            var tt = t as MyType;

            if (t == null || (arrT != null && !arrT.IsFull()) || (tt != null && !tt.IsFull()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- I don't get the `t as Array` part? `t` here should always be `MyType`. Maybe you're thinking of jagged arrays `[][]` where `GetValue` could return an array. It could be because I confusingly call `IsFull` in the method, but that's also a method on `MyType.IsFull`

Comment: @GP89 oh you're absolutely right, I did confuse it with jagged arrays